# How to say 'Thirty minutes away by foot'?

Tags: phrases

Can I use: 'Thirty minutes away by foot'? Or how should I write this sentence properly? I want to say that: 'I will be living less than thirty minutes away, by bicycle or by (foot/walking), from the college'?

Comment: _My place is just a 30-minute walk from the college._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that “30 minutes away *on* foot” is more colloquially standard in American English. Otherwise, what you're saying sounds fine.

Comment: This may be regional; I find *by* acceptable. It mixes well with "by plane" or "by boat".

Comment: Except for ?"colloquially standard in American English", it seems OK the way it is to me.

Answer (score 0):

In descending order of usage and clarity... "30-minute walk from the college," "30 minutes by foot from the college," "30 minutes on foot from the college,"

"30-minute bike ride" or "30 minutes by bike."  I wouldn't say "30 minutes on bike."  You could use "30 minutes on *a/the* bike" but that seems to relate more to the time you spend on the bike vs. the trip. Like, "What did you do at the gym?"  "Oh, I spent 30 minutes on the bike and then did push ups."

Comment: Hello, Scott. As Matt Gutting has said, "What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references." [ [But Google Ngrams for  "minutes by foot from" & "minutes on foot from"  don't support your claim](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minutes+by+foot+from%2Cminutes+on+foot+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cminutes%20by%20foot%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminutes%20on%20foot%20from%3B%2Cc0).]